# How to read json attributes values to shell script without jq

Tags: json, shell

my curl command returns a json response

```
[{ "id":3, "start_time" : "x","end_time" : "x","total_time" : "x"}]
```

how do I get the json  value into a variable in the shellscript
I want to read without jq
I am loking for output
id=3
start_time=x

Comment: `bash` doesn't have a JSON parser built in, so there is no good way, in general, to do this.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use jq?

Comment: "I want to do something, but I don't want to use the correct tool". Change your preference and use the correct tool.  Whatever is preventing you from using `jq` needs to be addressed, since that is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

you could use python e.g.

```
echo '[{ "id":3, "start_time" : "x","end_time" : "x","total_time" : "x"}]' | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print obj[0]["id"]; print obj[0]["start_time"]';
```